# On Increasing the load on server , jmeter starts getting javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

Tags: ssl, https, server, jmeter, openssl

I am trying to test my server through jmeter. Everything runs smoothly when there is not enough load on the server. But when I start loading the server from jmeter, I start getting

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

error for few requests.

I suspected it to be a cipher exchange problem. But nothing seemed to work (either changing the SSL configurations on the jmeter side or on my server side).

Now I suspect it to be the problem with connection acceptance from my server when it is given heavy load.

Here is the image of error stack on jmeter :

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is not reproducible for lesser loads it clearly doesn't have anything to do with the cipher exchange. It indicates the [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing) connected with the increased load.

So I would recommend inspecting your server and JMeter logs, it should have sufficient information with regards to what's going on at the network layer. If it doesn't - you can increase JMeter logging verbosity by:

- [Adding the next line to *system.properties* file](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https)

  ```
  javax.net.debug=all
  ```
- [Adding the next linex to *log4j2.xml* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging):

  ```
  <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.util.HttpSSLProtocolSocketFactory" level="debug" />
  <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.util.JsseSSLManager" level="debug" />
  ```

It might also be the case that either your application server or JMeter simply got overloaded, make sure to have monitoring in place in order to be sure that they have enough headroom in terms of CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, etc. You can use either built-in monitoring tools of your operating system(s) or an [APM tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management) or [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) for this.